# phpMyAdmin: Remove Table Drop and Empty Controls

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm not sure this is the place to post this as there are very few questions tagged phpMyAdmin; I thought of stackoverflow, but it's not really programming. In any case, mods should feel free to move this to whatever SE site is appropriate...

I'm looking for a configuration option that would hide the Drop and Empty tabs in the Table screens. I've looked at the [documentation](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/documentation/Documentation.html#config) and there are all kinds of config options, even down to letting you change the background colors of the various panes. Fun, but not as useful as controlling access to the Drop and Empty table tables would be...

Can anyone point me to where I can change this? I know I've worked on hosted servers that had those tabs hidden, so it has to be possible somehow.

Comment: Just curious, how is it useful to get rid of those tabs? There are other ways to perform drop and empty without them being available.

Comment: Yes, there are. But if you deliberately write a drop query, it's your own fault if you lose something. The tabs are just too easy to click on accidentally.

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to avoid accidentally clicking drop and empty, create a user without drop and empty privileges for accessing the database from inside phpmyadmin. That seems a bit easier than trying to remove those tabs from code.

Comment: So then if I wanted to legitimately run a drop query, I'd need to log out and log back in as a different user? Thanks for the suggestion, but no.

Comment: You must run a lot of legitimate drop and empty queries. I was unaware...

Comment: Not a lot, no, but once you're logged in as a user with the ability to use them, you have the tabs back. You run your query, then forget to log out and log back in (yet again) as the lower-level user, and you're back where you started with the tabs being there and too easy to click on by mistake. Call my desire to do this frivolous if you want, but given that there are config options to change background colors, I don't think this should be impossible.

Comment: I agree with you, the option should exist, if it doesn't. Hacking the php seems overkill though if that's what it takes to get this option. If you upgrade phpmyadmin you'll have to hack it again or at least verify it. That might suit some though. In phpmyadmin, to be safe I usually work with reduced privileges similar as having to sudo into root on linux. Its preference. Depends on how you use it.

Comment: [Voting for this answer, and...] @EmmyS: Changing the background color is *only* an interface decision. What you want has greater implications than just hiding a UI element. Don't try and equate them. You're in (probably denied) feature request territory. @JMC gave you the arguably "correct" solution from any reasonable access management perspective. Simply *hiding* the ability to do this isn't a good idea, and saying "if you do it it's your fault" isn't really the approach that's going to be taken by anyone writing software to manage databases that could take out an entire business if broken.

Comment: And [here's where you file a feature request](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?atid=377408&group_id=23067) (The character counter apparently includes markup, and wouldn't let me add it in.

Comment: "yet my boss managed to do it twice last week" - give your boss an account without drop and empty privileges.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, phpMyAdmin colours those tabs in red to attempt to avoid clicks, and when you click them you will either get a Javascript confirmation alert or go to another page that has the confirmation. So it's very difficult to accidentally drop an entire table.

If that's still not satisfactory I would suggest editing the CSS. You'll need to edit the file `themes/original/css/theme_right.css.php` (or a different folder instead of `original` if that's not your theme). Add this near the top, after the first PHP section:

```
.tabcaution { display: none; }
```

UPDATE: As of version 3.4.0, PHPMyAdmin appears to have removed those buttons from the main menu and they are now under the Operations page for each table.

Comment: +1 for "It's very difficult to accidentally drop an entire table." - if confirmations on `DELETE`, `TRUNCATE`, and `DROP` are insufficient, whomever is blindly clicking "OK" to confirmations needs an account with more restrictive permissions: text-based SQL queries are also allowed and those have similar potential for data loss (though phpMyAdmin still confirms on `DELETE`, `TRUNCATE`, and `DROP`). I'd be more worried about `UPDATE`'s without `WHERE` clauses.

Comment: I agree that it's difficult to accidentally drop an entire table, and yet my boss managed to do it twice last week, which is why I was hoping there was a way to hide the tabs without completely removing the access.

Comment: @EmmyS: I just updated my copy of phpMyAdmin to 3.4.0 and those buttons are not on the main menu any more. So just update phpMyAdmin and your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of is to edit the php. I've found what looks like the code that generates those in db_structure.php (this is 3.3.7). Look for lines with the words TRUNCATE and DROP in them.

One reason that those hosted servers had them hidden could be because the database user didn't have the privileges to do that, but I can't see anything in the code to check those privileges, so maybe the hosting companies edited the php too.

Comment: ...though be aware that if you do this, and you probably shouldn't, you'll be responsible for maintaining the hack every time the software is updated.